# Android - to wait or to flicker (loading messages)

Tags: android, multithreading

Up until now I've artificially inserted delays into background tasks to make sure that I show something is loading for example. I've just removed that, now for a single frame loading is displayed with a swirly thing then the compiled content is shown (because the background thread completes).

How do I solve this? I want to add a delay of a few milliseconds (to the main thread) after starting the background task, that way it goes from new activity to content seemingly instantly. However this delay seems to short, as suppose it took more than 5ms, loading would be shown which'd then flicker for things that take 6 or 7ms - Also, deliberately blocking the main thread - sounds stupid to me!

The other alternative is to delay the background thread, if something starts loading wait for time-take less a tenth of a second then post the result. That way loading appears and it looks as if is loaded.

Adding delays like this reminds me of times when I'd remove the delays and claim I made it several times faster, they were not good days. It also makes it more complicated for me because suppose I have 5 background things, I don't want them to come though one at a time separated by a 10th of a second (Filesystem cache means the second one would be a lot faster) and AsyncTask is so nice.

Perhaps wait for all tasks to complete then process the result?

Anyway I am sure this problem has been faced and answered before.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main places to deal with this. The (1) background thread that does the work and (2) on in the UI thread when handling the UI changes when the background task starts and ends. Also of importance is whether the task will be expected to always last about the same time, or if it can sometimes take a lot longer (i.e. downloading something will depend on network and servers).

If you can expect that it'll always be quick and in response to user actions, you can probably get away without showing the Loading message.

If you add extra duration to the task, that is time that is 'wasted' every time. The concern of the background task is to get the task done, not about how to present the results to the user.

The other place is in the UI side of things. How to present results to the user once they are ready. Consider having a 'minumum' time. This means that the 'Loading' message will last at least a certain amount of time on screen. If the task takes longer than this, then no extra time is added to the task duration. This can be done by starting a timeout when starting the background task, and only hiding the "Loading" message once *both* are finish. That is, switching from Loading to result takes as long as the longest of both.

The other thing that you can do to help is wait a certain amount of time before showing the "Loading" message. So if you have tasks that can sometimes be instantaneous this delay before showing the message will prevent the flash.

A third tool that you can use is animations. For example fading in and out the loading message and spinning progress indicator. If the background task completes quickly then the loading message will be somewhat dim, or at least it will not abruptly show up and disappear.

For example, [`ContentLoadingProgressBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ContentLoadingProgressBar.html) does both these things.